# What is the argument of connectionSocket.recv?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In `connectionSocket.recv(1024)`, does `1024` mean the buffer size of the server in Python or does it mean the buffer size of the socket?

I have just started to learn Python so I am a beginner. However, I am the kind of person who cannot move forward without knowing the actual meaning.

Comment: What do you mean by “buffer size of the server”?

Answer (score 0):

It's the [maximum size of data to be received at once](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) (in bits).

The number is typically a power of 2 (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128...) because of conventions in hardware and networking.